# Run CELERY as Daemon in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, celery, daemon

How to run celery as Daemon service in ubuntu instead of running "`celery -A projname worker -l info`" command each time.

I am using celery 3.1.8 version....

Comment: One can use circus for demonizing celery even with python3 check this for details http://aameer.github.io/circus-as-an-alternative-to-supervisor/

Answer (score 4):

You can make celery into a daemon with the [init.d script](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd) from celery's repo (Save it to `/etc/init.d/`). You will also need to create a [configuration file](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-configuration) for the script to load in `/etc/default/celeryd`.

Here's the full [celery doc](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can make celery worker as a daemon using a tool called [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

It's a simple process manager, 
you can find an example [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/extra/supervisord/) on how to configure your worker using supevisor's config file.

Answer (score 1):

It is a question asked a long time ago, but I think it is worth to give an answer.

You can follow bellow steps:

1. Create a celery user

```
sudo adduser celery
```

2. Create the init script

```
sudo nano celeryd
```

And copy the [celeryd](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd) and past to the created `celeryd`.
and then

```
chmod +x celeryd
sudo mv celeryd /etc/init.d/
```

3. Create a configuration file

- Create the empty /etc/default/celeryd configuration file for the init script

```
sudo touch /etc/default/celeryd
sudo vim /etc/default/celeryd
```

- Edit the above celeryd according to your project.

```
 # Names of nodes to start
 #   most people will only start one node:
 CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
 #   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
 #   for each in CELERYD_OPTS
 #CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
 #   alternatively, you can specify the number of nodes to start:
 #CELERYD_NODES=10

 # Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
 #CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
 #CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"
 CELERY_BIN="/opt/django_projects/your_proj/your_env/bin/celery"

 # App instance to use
 # comment out this line if you don't use an app
 CELERY_APP="your_proj"
 # or fully qualified:
 #CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

 # Where to chdir at start.
 CELERYD_CHDIR="/opt/django_projects/your_proj/"

 # Extra command-line arguments to the worker
 CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
 # Configure node-specific settings by appending node name to arguments:
 #CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 -c 8 -c:worker2 4 -c:worker3 2 -Ofair:worker1"

 # Set logging level to DEBUG
 #CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"

 # %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
 CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
 CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

 # Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
 #   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
 #   a user/group combination that already exists (e.g., nobody).
 CELERYD_USER="celery"
 CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

 # If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
 # and owned by the userid/group configured.
 CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

4. Create logs directory

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/celery
sudo chown -R celery: /var/log/celery
```

5. Verbose the init-scripts

```
sudo sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

6. Enable the daemon

```
sudo update-rc.d celeryd defaults
sudo service celeryd start
```

Well, I hope it will be helpful for you.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for step-by-step guide!! Im getting error  on step 5, saying "/bin/bash: multi: command not found"