# How to setup celery as daemon

Tags: django, celery

I am faced with necessity to setup celery as daemon for my django project on Ubuntu 16.04 server while doing it I met several misunderstandings which I will describe in my question. I know that by the rules of Stack asked should should ask only one clear question but I will ask several in one question because first question come from second etc.

For tune celery as daemon I decide to use `SystemD`.  In documentation [Demonization celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#daemonizing) provide a guide but it isn't so clear as I want maybe it's because I am beginner. My first question is: should I setup separately celery and celerybeat? 
Here is  documentation provided example of configuration

```
[Unit] 
Description=Celery Service    
After=network.target 

[Service] 
Type=forking 
User=celery 
Group=celery 
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery 
WorkingDirectory=/opt/celery 
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN}    multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \ -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \ --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}' 
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \ --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'  
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \ -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \ --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}' 

[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

All my misunderstandings relate to this piece of code and next question is:

What `user` and `group` I should specify in Service part of configuration? in documentation example above celery specified for user and group but when I checked users and groups on my Ubuntu I haven't celery user and group should I create this kind of user and group if answer is yes what rights I should provide for celery user and group?  Or I should specify in user and group settings my Ubuntu user under which I am working on server?

Next question is related to all variables which used to specify different parts of settings for example in above configuration example in `ExecStart` settings have multiple variables

```
${CELERY_BIN}   
${CELERYD_NODES} 
${CELERY_APP} 
${CELERYD_PID_FILE} 
${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} 
${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} 
${CELERYD_OPTS}'
```

Where I should specify this variables I think that it should be in django `settings.py` file but documentation above provide example which confused me maybe you can think why I can't to try configure this variables in settings.py rather than asking it here but I can't to test it because I don't have understanding about user and group question

Next question is about this setting

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
```

What I should specify here because I have not this file on my system?  Should I create it?  It's seems that is default settings for celery but I use django and all related settings to celery I specified in my django project settings.py file

Can anyone guide me?  Thank in advance

Comment: You can refer to my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525818/run-celery-as-daemon-in-ubuntu/64836876#64836876). wish help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create new user (`celery` is a good name). No need for any special attributes. Regular user should be fine. You define the necessary environment variables inside the /etc/conf.d/celery file.

Let's say you have created `celery` user in `/home/celery`... Log-in as that user, and create Python 3 virtual environment: `python3 -m venv ~/venv`. After that your `/etc/conf.d/celery` should have something like:

```
CELERY_BIN=/home/celery/venv/bin/celery   
CELERY_APP=myproject.myapp               # change this to however you named it
CELERY_OPTS=-Ofair -c12                  # any other options here
```

You need to define here all the vars you used in your systemd service file.

Also, there is no need for `/bin/sh -c` in Exec{Start/Stop/Reload} - `${CELERY_BIN} multi ...` will work as ${CELERY_BIN} should point to the Celery script in your virtual environment, which is executable.

Comment: I am confused with CELERY_APP variable.  Let's assume that my project located in following path `/home/isli/projects/forecast/forecast/celery.py` where my app was defined and named as forecast.  How I should specify my CELERY_APP variable?

Comment: How do you run Celery locally when you test? :) - Probably something like: `celery -A forecast.celery worker -c10 -l info -Ofair`, right? If that is the case, then `CELERY_APP=forecast.celery`

Comment: thank you can you also guide me about how I can test am I setup everything correct

Answer (score 10):

I too struggled to understand and implement the instructions given in celeryproject.org's daemonisation guide for *systemd*. Finally I just used general daemonisation instructions and it worked. I am using Flask, but I suppose this should work for you also :

This is my *celery.service* file. I have flask and celery running in a virtual environment (*venv*) :

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=your_username
WorkingDirectory=/home/your_username/your_projdir
Environment="PATH=/home/your_username/your_projdir/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/your_username/your_projdir/venv/bin/celery worker -A celery_worker.celery --loglevel=info

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

You could add more commands here, and choose to include *EnvironmentFile*, but this simple setup worked well for me.

Comment: I've wasted a day try to follow the official docs which advocate "celery multi". Your answer worked well for me, after I made **-A main.celery**  the *first* option, and changed **--loglevel=info** to **--loglevel=INFO**